# Rapache, can not use passed argument

Tags: php, r, rapache

i used boxcox transformation and got a numeric variable lambda,
but i can not read it in the next page,
if i do:
lambda<-GET$lambda
i can not later read the variable "lambda"
important to mention that the operation fails when between <%,%>,
but in HTML or php  it works,
does anyone have a solution?

The Code:

```
<?php
echo $_GET[lambda]; <!!!!!This echo command work OK!!!!!>
if (isset($_GET["check_if_press"]) && $_GET["check_if_press"] == "Submit"){ 
if($_GET[clean_decide]=="yes") {
echo"
<%
csvDF<- read.csv(GET$name1, header=TRUE)
lambda<-GET$lambda <!!!!! This 2 lines create an error!!!!!!>
print(lambda)
k<-1
CleanLots<-NULL
Removed<-NULL
a<-NULL
i<-1
.
.
.
%>
";
}else {echo "no";}
}
?>
```

Yonatan Shalev

Comment: O, I forgot to mention that it's a php error, not rapache.
I know that because when it's a php error the page just doesn't show up

Comment: You already asked this on the rApache list. It's probably sufficient to ask in one place or the other.

Answer (score 2):

Hard for me to test because your setup isn't replicable, but did you mean

```
lambda <- $_GET[lambda]
```

As I mentioned in your previous questions: in order for you to stop having errors that you can't track down every five minutes, you need to separate the different tasks in your code.  That way you can determine if the problem is with `rApache` or your plain R code.

Comment: I didnt mean to write lambda <- $_GET[lambda]. 
lambda<-GET$lambda is the way to pass variables to r when variables are coming from GET...
There is no problem with the r code. It works ok. But when we add the lambda it stops working only on the web...
The page doesn't show up.It's every strange...

Comment: If you `print(str(GET))` before the error, then you'll be able to see whether or not it contains an item named `lambda`.